# Changing Apache2 ports on Debian system

Tags: apache, port

I've had a crack at changing the default port for Apache2 to listen on, but it's not working.

I edited my ports.conf file to look like this:

```
# Edited:

NameVirtualHost *:9000
Listen 9000

# Kept the same:

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

And then adjusted my VHost file (and symlinked it to sites-enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:9000>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.co.uk
    ServerName www.mysite.co.uk
    ServerAlias mysite.co.uk

    # Directory Root
    DocumentRoot /home/mysite/www

    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog /home/mysite/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/mysite/log/www.log "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""

</VirtualHost>
```

For the records, if I replace all the port references (9000) to 80, the site works again.

At the DocumentRoot is a WordPress site. Is it possible WordPress could be re-writing the port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.

The bit at the end of my question sent me searching for WordPress hindrances and I pretty much found my answer in the first 2 minutes. I'll include my fix for others having the same issue...

It seems WordPress gets a bit funky with port numbers, and attempts to remove them if the WordPress Address or Site Address settings don't corroborate with the port you're trying to access it from.

Go to Settings->General in the WordPress admin panel and add the port `:9000` to your `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` values.

Remember to do this before changing the port via Apache otherwise you'll have to change it back in order to update the WordPress settings. Note that your WordPress will go cock-eyed while you re-configure Apache to the correct ports.